# Binomial Congruence

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

How can we show that $\dbinom{pm}{pn}\equiv\dbinom{m}{n}\pmod {p^3}$ where $m$ and $n$ are nonnegative integers and $p$ is a prime such that $p \geq 5$ ? I can do it for $\mod p^2$ but I am stuck here.

Comment: Could you give some background, e.g., where did you come across this question and what have you tried yourself?

Comment: See if you can adapt [this](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mampsj/Binomial.pdf) proof.

Comment: Please refer to http://jmobile.maa.org/i/240475/71

Comment: See http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X90901136

Answer (score 7):

Since:
$$\binom{pm}{pn}=\frac{(pm)(pm-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(p(m-n)+1)}{(pn)!}=\binom{m}{n}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\prod_{h=1}^{p-1}\frac{(m-n+k)p+h}{kp+h}$$
it is enough to show that
$$\binom{kp-1}{p-1}\equiv{1}\pmod{p^3}\tag{1}$$
for any $k$ and for any $p\geq 5$, that is also known as Glaisher's theorem. It happens that:
$$\binom{kp-1}{p-1}=\frac{((k-1)p+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot((k-1)p+p-1)}{(p-1)!}=\prod_{h=1}^{p-1}\left(1+\frac{(k-1)p}{h}\right),\tag{2}$$
so:
$$\binom{kp-1}{p-1}\equiv 1+p(k-1) H_{p-1} + (k-1)^2 p^2\cdot\!\!\!\!\!\!\sum_{1\leq h_1<h_2\leq p-1}\frac{1}{h_1 h_2}\pmod{p^3},\tag{3}$$
but since $H_{p-1}\equiv 0\pmod{p^2}$ by Wolstenholme's theorem, we just need to prove that
$$\sum_{1\leq h_1<h_2\leq p-1}\frac{1}{h_1 h_2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(H_{p-1}^2-H_{p-1}^{(2)}\right)\equiv 0\pmod{p},\tag{4}$$
that is trivial since $H_{p-1}^{(2)}\equiv 0\pmod{p}$.

Comment: The primes $p=2$ and $p=3$ arise as exceptions just because in the RHS of the identity $$\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}j^2 = \frac{p(p-1)(2p-1)}{6}$$ there is a $6=2\cdot 3$ in the denominator.

Comment: Why is it enough to show (1)? I am not sure the denominators agree mod $p^3$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: denominators? I don't exactly recall the details now, but I believe that $\binom{pm}{pn}$ can be written as a product of $\binom{m}{n}$ and binomial coefficients (so, integers) of the form $\binom{kp-1}{p-1}$. I'll check this in a few moments.

Comment: Not sure I do. Are you claiming that the $kp+h$'s in the denominators on the LHS somehow correspond to the $h$'s in the denominators on the RHS?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: about the very first equation (it does not have a tag), I am just re-writing the innermost product as a binomial coefficient.

Comment: But how does that binomial coefficient end up being $\dbinom{kp-1}{p-1}$ ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: $$\prod_{h=1}^{p-1}\frac{(m-n+k)p+h}{kp+h}=\prod_{h=1}^{p-1}\frac{(m-n+k)p+h}{h}/\prod_{h=1}^{p-1}\frac{kp+h}{h}=\binom{(m-n+k+1)p-1}{p-1}/\binom{(k+1)p-1}{p-1},$$ but those binomial coefficients are just $1\pmod{p^3}$.

Comment: Ah, that was a division there! That works, nice.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: yes, sorry if I made a mess before, It was just an answer I gave a long time ago. Nice to meet you, anyway, I still remember of you from the time of IMO competitions and Forum Geometricorum :)

Comment: Now that I fully understand it, this is a nice proof! (Although it wouldn't hurt to say that $H_{p-1}$ means $\sum\limits_{h=1}^{p-1} \dfrac{1}{h}$, and that $H^{(2)}_{p-1}$ means $\sum\limits_{h=1}^{p-1} \dfrac{1}{h^2}$.)