# For any prime $p>3$ show that $C_{np}^{p}-C_{np}^{2p}+C_{np}^{3p}-C_{np}^{4p}+...+(-1)^{n-1}C_{np}^{np} \equiv 1\pmod{p^3}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

Let $n$ be a positive integer. For any prime $p>3$ show that
$$C_{np}^{p}-C_{np}^{2p}+C_{np}^{3p}-C_{np}^{4p}+...+(-1)^{n-1}C_{np}^{np} \equiv 1\pmod {p^3}$$ Where $C_{n}^{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. (*)

I tried this by brute force - plugging (*) everywhere and simplify, but I couldn't make it produce the desired result. It would be appreciated if somebody would show me some tricks for a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Binomial Congruence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850724/binomial-congruence) (see also [Bailey's paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X90901136)) we have that for any prime $p\geq 5$,
$$\dbinom{np}{kp}\equiv\binom{n}{k}\pmod {p^3}.$$
Hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\binom{np}{kp}\equiv-\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}=-(1-1)^n+\binom{n}{0}=1\pmod {p^3}.$$